# Google Cloud Composer - Create Environment - with a few compute engine instances - That is expensive

Tags: google-compute-engine, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am new to Google Cloud Composer and following the QuickStart instruction, Create the Environment, Load Dag, Check Airflow, and Delete the Environment.

But in (real life) production use case, after we finish load dag files and run them in the environment. Should we delete the Google Cloud Composer Environment? Because there might be several compute instances in that composer and doing nothing now. It is expensive.

But if I delete the environment, then I would lose the access to its airflow web portal, and I could not check the processing logs of my processing on the deleted environment.

So what should I do? In real life production case, should I delete or not delete the environment after the processing is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Airflow (and therefore Cloud Composer) is for orchestrating workflows, not for ETL batch jobs that only require transient compute resources. Similarly to how you wouldn't turn a server off just because a scheduled cron task isn't running, Composer environments are meant to be long-running compute resources that are always online, such that you can schedule repeating workflows whenever necessary (whether that be per second, daily, etc)

In a real production case, a Composer environment should always be left running, or no DAGs will be scheduled when it is down. If you have a development environment and wish to save money, then you can resize the Composer environment's attached GKE cluster to 0 nodes so you won't be billed for them. Similarly, if you don't think you're running enough DAGs to justify the cost, consider smaller worker machine sizes.